# SQL group by year+month, but get months w/o records too

Tags: sql, db2

I want to group the content of a table by text and then by year + month and add up the count:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
|    TEXT     | T1_YEAR | T1_MONTH | T1_COUNT |
+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
| First Text  |    2013 |        1 |        1 |
| First Text  |    2013 |        2 |        1 |
| First Text  |    2013 |        3 |        1 |
| First Text  |    2013 |        5 |        1 |
| First Text  |    2013 |        6 |        3 |
| First Text  |    2013 |        7 |        1 |
| First Text  |    2013 |        8 |        3 |
| First Text  |    2013 |        9 |        1 |
| First Text  |    2013 |       10 |        2 |
| Second Text |    2013 |        1 |        2 |
| Second Text |    2013 |        2 |        5 |
| Second Text |    2013 |        3 |        8 |
| Second Text |    2013 |        4 |        5 |
| Second Text |    2013 |        5 |       23 |
| Second Text |    2013 |        6 |        9 |
| Second Text |    2013 |        7 |       27 |
+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

```
select 
  table1.TEXT text, 
  year(table1.timestamp) t1_year, 
  month(table1.timestamp) t1_month, 
  count (*) as t1_count
from table1
group by 
  table1.TEXT, 
  year(table1.timestamp), 
  month(table1.timestamp)
with ur;
```

Now I would also like an entry in the result table for the missing months with count 0.

I have read in other threads about temporary tables, but I haven't quite figured out how to make it work.

```
WITH DATERANGE(LEVEL, TEMP_DATE) AS (
  SELECT 1, CURRENT DATE - 5 MONTHS
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  UNION ALL SELECT LEVEL + 1, TEMP_DATE + 1 MONTH
    FROM DATERANGE
    WHERE LEVEL < 1000 AND TEMP_DATE < CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH
) SELECT TEMP_DATE FROM DATERANGE;
```

Temporary date table:

```
+------------+
| TEMP_DATE  |
+------------+
| 2013-09-05 |
| 2013-10-05 |
| 2013-11-05 |
| 2013-12-05 |
| 2014-01-05 |
+------------+
```

How can I achieve this easiest? I'm using DB2.

Comment: if there is no data for a specific month, but you want to show up in results as count(*) = 0 than you need to `left outer join` results to temp table or table variable that has numbers 1-12, this way if you pull numbers 1-12 from temp table and than join it, for the months that you are missing data you will still get a row. with count of 0

Comment: OK I see thanks. I inserted data with 'INSERT INTO SESSION.T_MONTHS VALUES (1);' in my temp table, but a select on my temp table select * from SESSION.T_MONTHS; returns an empty result set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use OLAP fonctions for this problem. But I cannot write an example right now.

Comment: Adding ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS was the solution to preserve the rows in the temporary table. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42226/db2-will-not-insert-into-created-temp-table-that-i-created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a temp table with the same sort of values (year and month).  Then you can outer join from that to your data table:

```
select
dt.theyear,
dt.themonth,
sum(t1_count)

from
DateTable DT
left outer join table1 t1
  on dt.theyear = t1.t1_year
  and dt.theMOnth = t1.t1_month
group by
dt.theyear,
dt.themonth
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle example (SQL Server, because they don't have DB2, but it should translate just fine):
[SQL FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a3fb/1)